# Error trying to import datetime value into a Postgresql table

Tags: postgresql, datetime, import, format

I have a csv file with several columns having a datetime value with a format like this: `'2008-12-03-18.01.46.000916'`. I am trying to import the data using the import capability built in DBeaver and also using postgresql **COPY** statement. Both fail.

I am using `'yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSS'` as import format in DBeaver and I don't see a way to tell COPY to use a datetime format to read it. I tried `DATEFORMAT` as you see here but it doesn't work:

```
COPY myTable FROM '/tmp/myDataWithDotsInTime.csv'
WITH (FORMAT csv, HEADER false, DELIMITER ',',  DATEFORMAT 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss');
```

Postgresql function `to_datetime` uses a different format than DBeaver and works, but I don't find a way to tell COPY to use it:

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, to_timestamp('2008-12-03-18.01.46.000916', 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24.MI.SS') AS ts
```

Comment: `copy` into a temporary table as text and then insert into `mytable` with a select from it.

Answer (score 1):

In similar cases (specific formats or a transformation is needed) I use the approach below, generic enough and usually solves the issue.

- Create a temporary table similar to `mytable` with the timestamp column as text;
- `copy` into the temporary table;
- `insert` into `mytable` with a select from temporary table.

Assuming that the target field in `mytable` is `ts`

```sql
create temporary table the_temporary_table (like myTable);
alter table the_temporary_table alter ts type text;

COPY myTable -- Your COPY statement w/o DATEFORMAT 
FROM '/tmp/myDataWithDotsInTime.csv'
WITH
(
 FORMAT csv, 
 HEADER false, 
 DELIMITER ','
);

insert into myTable
 select <..fields before ts..>,
        to_timestamp(ts, 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24.MI.SS.US') ts,
        <..fields after ts..>
 from the_temporary_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use DBeaver by adding extra SSS in the format for the microseconds in the end (in the import settings) to meet the input criteria like this:

```
yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS
```

Thanks to DBeaver support person.

Also thanks to Stefanov.sm for your work-around solution that works with the COPY statement. However, In my case I prefer the DBeaver solution because I can import my CSV file from my PC instead of having to copy the CSV file to the Linux back-end to use COPY.